# how to assert catch promise with sinon and chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, chai, sinon

We have a method in our CLI which uses method returning a promise to print message to user.

```
exports.handler = (argv) => {
  let customUtils = new Utils(argv);

  Utils.deploy()
    .then(res => console.log(`Ressource was deployed`))
    .catch(e => {
      console.error(`Ressource was not deployed`);
      console.error(e);
      process.exit(1);
    });
}
```

We are looking for a way to test console errors and process exit in case of `deploy()` promise rejection.

We tried using sandbox stub then assert in an async test:

```
describe('when promise is errored', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    utilsStub = sandbox.stub(Utils.prototype, 'deploy').rejects('rejected');
    processStub = sandbox.stub(process, 'exit');
    consoleStub = sandbox.stub(console, 'error');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should call deploy and log the error before exiting', async () => {
    await handler({});

    expect(utilsStub).to.have.been.called;
    expect(console.error).to.have.been.called;
  });
});
```

This test doesn't work: `AssertionError: expected error to have been called at least once, but it was never called`.

The same happens when we `expect(process.exit).to.have.been.called;`. It's never called.

We successfuly tested the `then` part in a similary way:

```
describe('when promise is resolved', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    utilsStub = sandbox.stub(Utils.prototype, 'deploy').callsFake(() => Promise.resolve('some text'));
    consoleStub = sandbox.stub(console, 'log');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should call deploy and print success message', async () => {
    await handler({});

    expect(utilsStub).to.have.been.called;
    expect(console.log).to.have.been.calledWith('Ressource was deployed');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things to fix the source and test file.

For source file, we must use `customUtils` to call `deploy()` function. Since, you can use `async/await`, convert it from Promise can produce better code.

```
exports.handler = async argv => { // put async
  let customUtils = new Utils(argv);
  try {
    await customUtils.deploy(); // change to await and use customUtils
    console.log(`Ressource was deployed`);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`Ressource was not deployed`);
    console.error(e); 
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
```

For test file, nothing changes

```
describe('when promise is errored', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    utilsStub = sandbox.stub(Utils.prototype, 'deploy').rejects('rejected');
    processStub = sandbox.stub(process, 'exit');
    consoleStub = sandbox.stub(console, 'error');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should call deploy and log the error before exiting', async () => {
    await handler({});

    expect(utilsStub).to.have.been.called;
    expect(console.error).to.have.been.called;
    expect(process.exit).to.have.been.called; // add it
  });
});
```

UPDATED:

In case want to still use promise, we have to make sure we return the promise.

```
exports.handler = (argv) => {
  let customUtils = new Utils(argv);

  return customUtils.deploy() // <== specify return here
    .then(res => console.log(`Ressource was deployed`))
    .catch(e => {
      console.error(`Ressource was not deployed`);
      console.error(e);
      process.exit(1);
    });
};
```

Hope it helps

Comment: it works but I don't really get what's different. Using then().catch() should have worked then?

Comment: @BlackHoleGalaxy it won't because we didn't specify return statement of the promise. See my updated answer :)

Comment: got it. Forgot defining async method transforms in kind of automatic promise return.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be able `await` the result of `exports.handler` before you test your assertions. You *are* awaiting it, but `exports.handler` is not returning the promise, so there's nothing to await in the test — `exports.handler` returns undefined immediately so the test runs the assertions in the same event loop before `console.error` can be called.

I'm not sure why you aren't seeing similar problems in the test where the promise resolves. (Maybe worth checking that that test fails properly)

This should help:

```
exports.handler = (argv) => {
  let customUtils = new Utils(argv);

  //Utils.deploy() // <- is that a typo?

    return customUtils.deploy()
      .then(res => console.log(`Ressource was deployed`))
      .catch(e => {
          console.error(`Ressource was not deployed`);
          console.error(e);
          process.exit(1);
       });
}
```

Also in your tests you are creating a spy with:

```
consoleStub = sandbox.stub(console, 'error');
```

But writing the assertion directly on `console.error`. I don't think  this should work:

```
expect(console.error).to.have.been.called;
// maybe expect(consoleStub)...
```

With those changes the test passes for me and (more importantly) fails when I don't call `console.error` in the `catch`.

Comment: writing assertion agains console.error works. I manage to get the first test failing when changing success message for example.